# Таблицы в Python

Tags: python, математика, численные-методы

Добрый день! Недавно начал изучать Python, и возникла необходимость, загрузить данные, которые вычисляются в функциях в таблицу.

Приведу конкретно мой случай: Написал программу которая вычисляет приближенное значение интеграла несколькими методами на двух сетках(n и 2n), и мне нужно создать таблицу, где данные(в частности погрешности(error, error1 и их отношение)) были в ней отображены.

Т. е. таблицу необходимо сделать вида 4х3, где по вертикали были бы названия методов, а по горизонтали данные погрешностей.

Ниже привожу свой код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


a=50 //Начальная точка интервала интегрирования
b=60 //Конечная точка интервала интегрирования
n=10 //Число разбиений интервала
N=2*n //Удвоенное число разбиений интервала
h=(b-a)/n //Шаг сетки
hnew=(b-a)/N //Шаг удвоенной сетки

def f(x):
    return 1/(1+x)

ideal=0.179 //точное значение интеграла, а точнее значение, вычисленное по формуле Ньютона-Лейбница

def left(f, a, b, n):  //Метод левых прямоугольников
    Sum1 = sum([f((a + (k*h))) for k in range(0, n)]) //Вычисление на сетке с шагом h=(b-a)/n
    result1 = h * Sum1
    error=abs(ideal - result1)

    Sum2 = sum([f((a + (k*hnew))) for k in range(0, N)]) //Вычисление на удвоенной сетке
    result2 = hnew * Sum2
    error1=abs(ideal-result2)

    print('Формула левых прямоугольников '+ str(error)+' '+str(error1)+' '+str(error1/error))
    return result1
    return result2
left(f,a,b,n)


    def central(f,a,b,n):  //Метод центральных прямоугольников
        Sum = sum([f(((a + (k*h))+(a + ((k+1)*h)))/2) for k in range(0, n)])
        result = h * Sum
        error=abs(ideal - result)


        Sum1 = sum([f(((a + (k*hnew))+(a + ((k+1)*hnew)))/2) for k in range(0, N)])
        result1 = hnew * Sum1
        error1=abs(ideal - result1)


        print('Формула центральных прямоугольников '+ str(error)+' '+str(error1)+' '+str(error1/error))
        return result
        return result1
    central(f,a,b,n)


    def trapezy(f,a,b,n):  //Метод трапеций
        Sum = sum([(f(a + (k*h))+f(a + ((k+1)*h)))/2 for k in range(0, n)])
        result = h * Sum
        error=abs(ideal - result)


        Sum1 = sum([(f(a + (k*hnew))+f(a + ((k+1)*hnew)))/2 for k in range(0, N)])
        result1 = hnew * Sum1
        error1=abs(ideal - result1)

        print('Формула трапеций '+ str(error)+' '+str(error1)+' '+str(error1/error))
        return result
        return result1
    trapezy(f,a,b,n)


    def simpson(f,a,b,N): //Формула Симпсона
        Sum1 = sum([f(a+(2*k*hnew)) for k in range(1, n)])
        Sum2 = sum([f(a+(2*(k-1)*hnew)) for k in range(1, n+1)])
        result = hnew/3 * (f(a)+2*Sum1+4*Sum2+f(a+N*hnew))
        error=abs(ideal - result)


        Sum3 = sum([f(a+(2*k*hnew)) for k in range(1, N)])
        Sum4 = sum([f(a+(2*(k-1)*((b-a)/(2*N)))) for k in range(1, N+1)])
        result1 = ((b-a)/(2*N))/3 * (f(a)+2*Sum3+4*Sum4+f(a+2*N*((b-a)/(2*N))))
        error1=abs(ideal - result1)


        print('Формула Симпсона '+ str(error)+' '+str(error1)+' '+str(error1/error))
        return result
    simpson(f,a,b,n)
```

Comment: и в чем вопрос?

Comment: *"Таблицы в Python"* слишком расплывчато. Укажите вашу конкретную проблему прямо в заголовке, см. [ask]

Comment: приведите пример таблицы, которую вы хотите получить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала исправьте код. Например поправьте отступы и замените `//` на `#`.

После этого я бы изменил все функции таким образом чтобы они возвращали два значения (tuple) - т.е. вместо:

```
return result1
return result2
```

заменить на

```
return result1, result2
```

Теперь, когда все функции возвращают кортеж из двух значений, можно построить DataFrame:

```
funcs = {'left':left, 'central':central, 'trapezy':trapezy, 'simpson':simpson}

data = [func(f,a,b,n) for func in funcs.values()]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=funcs.keys(), columns=['error1','error2'])
```

Результат:

```
In [316]: df
Out[316]:
           error1    error2
left     0.180665  0.179854
central  0.179043  0.179047
trapezy  0.179058  0.179051
simpson  0.180373  0.180129
```